# Make matrix from 2 vectors

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to make matrix from 2 vectors. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
vec1=np.linespace(1,10,5)
vec2=vec1.reshape((-1,1))
matrix=np.dot(vec2,vec1)
```

The error says: shapes(5,1) and (5,) not aligned.

I tried operator `@` to make matrix, but it did not worked too.

Comment: Are you looking for a 5x5 result or a scalar?

Comment: Did you (re)read the `np.dot` docs before asking this?  It discusses what dimension combinations work. Do you want an inner or outer product?  Try `vec1.dot(vec1)` and `vec1*vec2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, `vec1 = np.linspace(1,10,5)`.

This is how I got the matrix 5*5:

```
import numpy as np
vec1=np.linspace(1,10,5).reshape(-1,1)
vec2=vec1.reshape((-1,1))
matrix=np.dot(vec2,vec1.T)
```

Your vec1 needs to be dimensioned to (5,1) and for the sake of dot product, you should transpose it so you can make a matrix.

Comment: Yes thats it, thans. I will accept the answer later.

Comment: Can you also explain, what is the difference between array shapes (x,) and (x,1) please?

Comment: A numpy array with shape (x, 1) is a two-dimensional array. Python knows that 2nd dimension. The second dimension just happens to have length 1. A numpy array with shape (x,) is a one-dimensional array. Note that for many applications and modules in Python you have to reshape your numpy array vector to a 2-d vector with size of 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a 5x5 matrix using simple multiplication in this case:

```
vec1 * vec1[:, None]
```

Or you can use `np.multiply.outer`:

```
np.multiply.outer(vec1, vec1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways of multiplying these 2 arrays:

```
In [144]: vec1
Out[144]: array([ 1.  ,  3.25,  5.5 ,  7.75, 10.  ])   # (5,) shape
In [145]: vec2                                         # (5,1) shape
Out[145]: 
array([[ 1.  ],
       [ 3.25],
       [ 5.5 ],
       [ 7.75],
       [10.  ]])
```

Element-wise with broadcasting:

```
In [146]: vec1*vec2     # (5) broadcasts with (5,1) to make (5,5)
Out[146]: 
array([[  1.    ,   3.25  ,   5.5   ,   7.75  ,  10.    ],
       [  3.25  ,  10.5625,  17.875 ,  25.1875,  32.5   ],
       [  5.5   ,  17.875 ,  30.25  ,  42.625 ,  55.    ],
       [  7.75  ,  25.1875,  42.625 ,  60.0625,  77.5   ],
       [ 10.    ,  32.5   ,  55.    ,  77.5   , 100.    ]])
```

dot/inner:

```
In [147]: vec1@vec1              # or dot, inner product
Out[147]: 201.875
In [148]: vec1@vec2           (5,) with (5,1) => (1,) result
Out[148]: array([201.875])
```

`outer` -same as the braodcasted.  There are other notations for this:

```
In [149]: np.outer(vec1, vec2)    # vec2 is flattened, np.outer(vec1,vec1)    
Out[149]: 
array([[  1.    ,   3.25  ,   5.5   ,   7.75  ,  10.    ],
       [  3.25  ,  10.5625,  17.875 ,  25.1875,  32.5   ],
       [  5.5   ,  17.875 ,  30.25  ,  42.625 ,  55.    ],
       [  7.75  ,  25.1875,  42.625 ,  60.0625,  77.5   ],
       [ 10.    ,  32.5   ,  55.    ,  77.5   , 100.    ]])
```

Can't `dot` (5,1) with (5,1)

```
In [150]: vec2@vec2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-150-5340db865439>", line 1, in <module>
    vec2@vec2
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 5 is different from 1)

In [153]: vec2.T@vec2          # (1,5) with (5,1) => (1,1)
Out[153]: array([[201.875]])
In [154]: vec2@(vec2.T)        # (5,1) with (5,1) => (5,5)
Out[154]: 
array([[  1.    ,   3.25  ,   5.5   ,   7.75  ,  10.    ],
       [  3.25  ,  10.5625,  17.875 ,  25.1875,  32.5   ],
       [  5.5   ,  17.875 ,  30.25  ,  42.625 ,  55.    ],
       [  7.75  ,  25.1875,  42.625 ,  60.0625,  77.5   ],
       [ 10.    ,  32.5   ,  55.    ,  77.5   , 100.    ]])
```

With `A@B` the last of `A` is paired with the 2nd to the last of `B`, reducing that `inner` pair of dimensions, leaving the outer 2.  This matrix-multiplication always features a **sum of products**.